# Bootstrap 3 second column collapse.. third column float right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the code below for Bootstrap 3, I am attempting to get the 3rd column to not stack. I want it to always stay top right just as the left most column stays top left. Is there a simple way? I thought about just excluding that section from bootstrap and just apply css to float right, but surely in Bootstrap, I can do this.

```
<header id="t3-header" class="container t3-header">
<div class="row">

    <!-- LOGO -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 logo"> I stay always top left</div> 

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">  I should stackunder 1st column as browser resizes </div>   

       <!-- I want this column to not stack below column 2 as the browser resizes. -->
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"> 
        I should always stay top right
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"> </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-6"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you've got to make the "*top right*" div, appear first in the cascade. To do this, first it as the first column, then you can use `pull-left` and `pull-right` helper classes to trick the first two columns:

Secondly, you could remove the `col-xs-12` alike in the example:

```
<header id="t3-header" class="container t3-header">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
            I should always stay top right
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 logo pull-left">
             I stay always top left
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 pull-left">
             I should stackunder 1st column as browser resizes
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Example:** http://www.bootply.com/ee3E67pujY

Comment: It works good... but it seems that on resize the 2nd column gets pushed down by the first. The first and last columns should always be level no matter how the browser resizes.

Comment: I change the second row to col-xs-12 col-md-8 pull-left. I need the second row to span all columns when it stacks under the logo

Comment: @chrislhardin Sorry, my first initial link had two containers, I hadn't realised the `<header>` had the class within it! Secondly, hopefully more like this?: http://www.bootply.com/YxoSGolNaP

Comment: that is extremely close... however, the second column needs to be on the same plane as the left until the browser gets to a tablet size. md I think...

Comment: @chrislhardin Last attempt ;) by adding `col-lg` then, making the second column be inline with the left pane http://www.bootply.com/VlM264UY9G